# How to apply logical OR to string operands in Swift 2?

Tags: string, swift, operands

I was trying to write an array which has classes that are "search queries" and I'm writing a for in loop that goes through them and picks out keywords using .rangeOfString:

```
import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"

class Search {
  var searchQuery:String

 init (query:String) {

    self.searchQuery = query

    }
}

var innocent = 0
var suspicious = 0
let keyword = "terrorist"

let queries = [Search(query: "How to be a terrorist"), Search(query: "How to join
Islamic State"), Search(query: "I want to be an astronaut")]

for query in queries {
if (query.searchQuery.rangeOfString(keyword) != nil){
    suspicious++
}
else {
    innocent++
  }
}

print(suspicious)
```

I want to make it such that I can have more than one keyword (e.g Islamic State and terrorist) so if it detects either of these it increments suspicious, but I can't apply an OR operator to two strings for some reason, not sure why. Does anyone have any idea how this may be possible in Swift?

I'm new to Swift and my programming is rusty in general, so any tips on how to improve this code in general (is there another, better way to do this besides .rangeOfString, how would filtering through search queries actually be done in real life in search engines?) is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Out of context, what is `string1 || string2` supposed to mean? That operation isn't well-defined. The `||` and `&&` operators work on Bool, and `...rangeOfString(..) != nil` returns a Bool.

Comment: Wouldn't it just mean that if either string1 or string2 is present it would return a Bool = true?

Comment: What I'm getting at is, if `string1 || string2` had some meaning—if it could stand in for a single string—then not only would you need to make sense of `rangeOfString(string1 || string2)`, but also things like `string0 + (string1 || string2)` or `(string1 || string2).split("\n")`. I'm just trying to point out why this doesn't work the way you asked.